# Pass submited file to web worker by refference with as little overhead as possible

Tags: javascript, web-worker, fileapi, transferable

I will have a web worker to parse huge text file (200000 lines, simple syntax though). I expect user to submit that file wia drag'n'drop or otherwise, obtaining a `File` object:

```
   var work = new Worker("parser.js")
   document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var dt    = e.dataTransfer;
       var files = dt.files;
       if(files.length>0) {
         var firstFile = files[0]
         var reader = new FileReader();
         //SEND FILE TO WORKER?
       }
   });
```

I heard of Transferable objects. Is there a way to *transfer* file to Worker? In a way that GUI thread will not be slowed by reading the file?

Comment: There is a great tutorial on this here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem-sync/ , you can even handle the fileReader on the worker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some browsers (can't find a compatibility table) support passing `File` objects through the web worker `postMessage` because they now use the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) to handle the message parameters. This would probably be the most efficient method for those browsers which support it.

[Further research](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/abstracting-the-web-worker-operative/) seems to indicate that structured cloning is supposed to be available on: Chrome 13+, Firefox 8+, IE10+, Opera 11.5+, Safari 5.1+

Comment: And that would basically mean the file is passed before even being opened, right?