# Set up large read file with FileReader into variable (non-blocking)

Tags: javascript, filereader

I read very large files using FileReader:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(bigFile);
```

Whenever the load ends I do the following:

```
reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    myGlobalFile = {data:reader.result, type:reader.file.type};
});
```

Setting up `myGlobalFile = {data:reader.result, type:reader.file.type};` can take some time and blocks actions of my user.

How can I set up the variable in a non-blocking way? Can I make use of FileReader `progress` to slowly add chunks to my variable?

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. What kind of data is it? What actions can the user do to that data without all of it?

Comment: The user can upload any file...the user doesn't do anything with the data. I don't want to upload the data to the server before the user submit it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Maybe try a Web Worker to handle the file? [This question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306015/pass-submited-file-to-web-worker-by-refference-with-as-little-overhead-as-possib)

Comment: Have you tried using a setTimeout with ‘0’ to read the file? I would at least try using setTimeout on the callback.